# Bootstrap Accordion data-parent but do not close

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

How do I prevent an accordion from closing again? So there's always one panel open. And you can't click it to close the panel. You have to click another panel to close it like how an accordion normally is, just prevent the active panel from closing. Thanks!

Comment: sir, try to mention some code piece or a fiddle to give us a clear overview and get the best of S.O.

Comment: I don't have a final code yet. I just used the bootstrap accordion example in w3school. And I haven't added anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do it using-

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjtyvvhe/) doing the same.